# Parameters to CUDA kernels

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

When invoking a CUDA kernel for a specific thread configuration, are there any strict rules on 
which memory space (device/host) kernel parameters should reside in and what type they should be?

Suppose I launch a 1-D grid of threads with

```
kernel<<<numblocks, threadsperblock >>> (/*parameters*/)
```

Can I pass an integer parameter `int foo` which is a **host**-integer variable, 
directly to the CUDA kernel? Or should I `cudaMalloc` memory for a single integer say `dev_foo` and then `cudaMemcpy` `foo` into `devfoo` and then pass `devfoo` as a kernel parameter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rules for kernel arguments are a logical consequence of C++ parameter passing rules and the fact that device and host memory are physically separate.

CUDA does not allow passing arguments by reference and you must be careful with pointers.

Specifically, you must pass parameters by value. Passing user-defined types requires that the default copy-constructor or your own copy-constructor (if present) does not contain any memory allocations (heap allocations with "new" or "malloc").

In summary pass-by-value works well for integral, floating point or other primitive types, and simple flat user-defined structs or class objects.

Comment: CUDA has come a long way since this answer was written.  Even when the answer was written I believe it should have been legal/possible to use pass-by-reference if the underlying data was pinned and mapped.  Today it is legal/possible to use pass-by-reference with [UM/managed memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-unified-memory-programming-hd) and also with pinned/mapped memory (e.g. `cudaHostAlloc()`)

Answer (score 5):

You only need to use `cudaMalloc()` and `cudaMemcpy()` for blocks of data. Not single `int`s and the like. You also can pass `struct`s as parameters, as long as they have no members pointing to a block of data in host memory.

So as a rule of thumb: if you are passing a pointer to a kernel, make sure it points into device memory.